# How create a single-file format of multiple documents with iOS for Windows, OSX, iPhone

Tags: ios4, filesystems, file-format

I'm working in a end-user app that will create documents that could have several files inside it.

The main resource is a sqlite database. The user can store several media files that are referenced form that database.

My first impulse is use [OSX Bundles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html), but that will show that are folders on windows.

Or put all the data inside the sqlite database, but will have issues when try to open large files.

Or maybe inside a zip file but need to compress/decompress.

Or maybe exist a magic trick to show a folder as a file under window...

Exist a working VFS (virtual file system) for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a well-known archiving format such as zip or tar, because I'm sure there are pre-made libraries for those that you can use. By the way, the ZIP format allows you to store files without compression as well.

Comment: Ok, but is possible to modify the zip file as easy as a bundle? Without compress/decompress cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) Application Edition, this is exactly what you are looking for and it's available for iOS as well as all other major platforms.

ZIP has the problem of ineffective modification - it's slow and resource-consuming.